# Good books on money creation and monetary theory?

Tags: money-supply, banking, central-banking

I just finished reading "Where does money come from?" (Ryan-Collins) on how commercial banks create the bulk of the money supply, and I am still hungry for more material that will help me understand things like the role of the central-bank and the government in creating money (both through money creation and public debt), the interaction between taxes, the money supply and inflation, and other related topics. I have a background in Finance but not in academic Economics. However, all suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

For a broad topic like this you can simply read some textbook. For example, Walsh Monetary Theory and Policy, you can skip all the math if that is not interesting for you.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an interest in historical economics and the basis of modern economic theory there is no way around *Keynes – The General Theory of Employment, Interest and Money*. Some parts might be challenging for contemporary readers, as we've moved past certain theoretical hurdles that were prevalent during Keynes's era.